# Cisco ASA -> Windows 2003 site-to-site VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

Is it possible to set up an ipsec site-to-site VPN between a Cisco ASA (5510) and a Windows 2003 Server?  (using RRAS or similar on the windows server)

And the followup question - if this is possible, can anyone point me to a resource with details of the settings needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not finding you a complete step-by-step resource, but AFAIK it's possible with an ASA.

I've configured interoperability for VPN tunnels with a Cisco PIX and several standards-based IPsec implementations (FreeSWAN, Symantec firewall device, Checkpoint firewall device), and I can't imagine it wouldn't work for Windows RRAS.

Some background on configuring the Windows side of this connection is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252735  (Yes, the document says "Windows 2000". Except for the fact that the GUI is a little better, the configuration is mostly the same in W2K3.)

A tunnel where both end-points (PIX and Windows) are machines directly connected to the Internet w/ static IP addresses using a pre-shared key ought to be fairly easy to configure, if you understand how IPsec works and can get your mind wrapped around the Windows tools for supporting IPsec.